# Solving the system of equations $12.3=D_0 e^{-Q/60R}$ and $24.1=D_0 e^{-Q/360R}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations, exponential-function

I am busy with 1st year engineering and I am struggling with this seemingly trivial math problem.

I have the following system equations:$$\begin{cases}12.3=D_0 e^{-Q/60R}\\ 24.1=D_0 e^{-Q/360R}\end{cases}$$

I have to solve for $D_0$, where $Q$ is an unknown but constant in both equations and $R = 8.314$ (Gas Constant). My lecturer was saying something about dividing the one equation by the other but that results in $\frac{D_0}{D_0}$ which leaves me with no variable to solve for.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

#### Edit

For all those who want to see how to do it:
\begin{align*}
\frac{12.3}{24.1} & = \frac{D_0}{D_0} \frac{e^{-Q/60R}}{e^{-Q/360R}}\\
\frac{12.3}{24.1} & = e^{-Q/60R -(-Q/360R)}\\
\frac{12.3}{24.1} & = e^{-Q(1/60R + 1/360R)}\\
\ln \frac{12.3}{24.1} & = -Q(1/60R+ 1/360R)\\
Q & = -\frac{\ln \frac{12.3}{24.1}}{1/60R + 1/360R}
\end{align*}

Comment: $\log$ both sides to get a more familiar linear system.

Comment: Thank you guys for all the help! I was also forgetting my basic exponent rules. Not the best thing to forget the night before semester tests.

Comment: Should I not rather ln both sides?

Comment: Yes, $\ln$ is another way of writing $\log$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dividing one equation by the other will give $\frac{12.3}{21.1} = \exp(-Q(\frac{1}{60R} - \frac{1}{360R}))$, which you can then solve for $Q$. Plugging $Q$ in to one of the equations will then let you solve for $D_0$.

Answer (score 3):

If $Q$ is a constant, then dividing one equation by the other will eliminate $D_{0}$ and allow you to solve for $Q$. Then once you have determined $Q$, plug into one of your equations to find, for example:

$D_{0} = \frac{12.3}{e^{-Q/60R}}$

Answer (score 2):

Hint: let $$x=e^{-Q/360R}$$

Note that $x^6 = e^{-Q/60R}$.

Solve for $x$ and $D_0$, then work out $Q$ from there.